# Write to streamsets sdc in groovy scripting

Tags: groovy, streamsets

I am pretty new to Streamsets and Groovy and I am updating my “Dev Raw Data Source” to “Groovy Scripting” as my input. The issue which I face here is, I have the below code in my “Groovy Scripting” and it throws an error.

**Groovy scripting**:

```
import com.streamsets.pipeline.stage.origin.scripting.*

record = sdc.createRecord("bulkUpdateRequestTemplate")
bulkUpdateRequestTemplate = "{ \"payload\": { \"objects\": { \"filter\": \"(equals(type,'configuration/entityTypes/Contract') and equals(attributes.ContractStatus, 'ACTIVE') and lt (attributes.ExpirationDate,'currentTimestampEpoch'))\", \"options\": \"searchByOv,ovOnly\" }, \"actions\": [ { \"operation\": \"UpdateAttribute\", \"operationParameters\": { \"attributeURI\": \"configuration/entityTypes/Contract/attributes/ContractStatus\", \"attributeValue\": \"INACTIVE\" } } ] } }"

record.value = bulkUpdateRequestTemplate
sdc.state['bulkUpdateRequestTemplate'] = record
```

**Error**:

```
com.streamsets.pipeline.api.StageException: SCRIPTING_10 - Script error in user script: javax.script.ScriptException: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: state for class: com.streamsets.pipeline.stage.origin.scripting.ScriptingOriginBindings
    at com.streamsets.pipeline.stage.origin.scripting.AbstractScriptingSource.produce(AbstractScriptingSource.java:124)
    at com.streamsets.pipeline.api.base.configurablestage.DPushSource.produce(DPushSource.java:44)
    at com.streamsets.datacollector.runner.StageRuntime.lambda$execute$1(StageRuntime.java:258)
    at com.streamsets.datacollector.runner.StageRuntime.execute(StageRuntime.java:232)
    at com.streamsets.datacollector.runner.StageRuntime.execute(StageRuntime.java:267)
    at com.streamsets.datacollector.runner.SourcePipe.process(SourcePipe.java:67)
    at com.streamsets.datacollector.runner.preview.PreviewPipelineRunner.runPushSource(PreviewPipelineRunner.java:233)
    at com.streamsets.datacollector.runner.preview.PreviewPipelineRunner.run(PreviewPipelineRunner.java:218)
    at com.streamsets.datacollector.runner.Pipeline.run(Pipeline.java:535)
    at com.streamsets.datacollector.runner.preview.PreviewPipeline.run(PreviewPipeline.java:39)
    at com.streamsets.datacollector.execution.preview.sync.SyncPreviewer.start(SyncPreviewer.java:227)
    at com.streamsets.datacollector.execution.preview.async.AsyncPreviewer.lambda$start$1(AsyncPreviewer.java:93)
    at com.streamsets.pipeline.lib.executor.SafeScheduledExecutorService$SafeCallable.lambda$call$0(SafeScheduledExecutorService.java:214)
    at com.streamsets.datacollector.security.GroupsInScope.execute(GroupsInScope.java:44)
    at com.streamsets.datacollector.security.GroupsInScope.execute(GroupsInScope.java:25)
    at com.streamsets.pipeline.lib.executor.SafeScheduledExecutorService$SafeCallable.call(SafeScheduledExecutorService.java:210)
    at com.streamsets.pipeline.lib.executor.SafeScheduledExecutorService$SafeCallable.lambda$call$0(SafeScheduledExecutorService.java:214)
    at com.streamsets.datacollector.security.GroupsInScope.execute(GroupsInScope.java:44)
    at com.streamsets.datacollector.security.GroupsInScope.execute(GroupsInScope.java:25)
    at com.streamsets.pipeline.lib.executor.SafeScheduledExecutorService$SafeCallable.call(SafeScheduledExecutorService.java:210)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at com.streamsets.datacollector.metrics.MetricSafeScheduledExecutorService$MetricsTask.run(MetricSafeScheduledExecutorService.java:88)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Am I missing something here? Please help.

Comment: `sdc.state` - there is no such property state. why do you think it should be there?

Comment: I have to maintain that record throughout the Streamsets scope for which I need that.

Comment: seems that state is not a part of sdc: https://docs.streamsets.com/portal/controlhub/3.14.x/onpremhelp/controlhub/UserGuide/ProtectionMethods/Method-Groovy.html

Answer (score 0):

state works only for processors and only within a given processor. It stores values you want to preserve between invocations of a processor.
Groovy Scripting origin doesn't have "invocations", it works constantly throughout the pipeline's execution, therefore it doesn't need "state".